# Loading xml from url in WIndows Universal APP

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

Dumb question, but anyway... I am wondering how can one load xml file from url (in Universal Project).

It was quite easy with WPF:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(url);
```

but this isn't working for me here and I really can not find a way around, it's annoying.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What would you do with the XML file ?

Comment: I have the same problem. In web, and Windows Phone 8, I have class to read XML from response. In universal win app it is not working. I need to read xml as stream from URL and parse it to object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpClient to do the request. (It's the Microsoft.Net.Http Nuget package.) Once you have a stream from it, there's an overload on XmlDocument.Load which accepts a stream. If you need it parsed as an object, skip XmlDocument.Load and use XmlSerializer instead.

```
using (HttpClientHandler hHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await hClient.GetAsync(URL);
    System.IO.Stream oStrm = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    XmlSerializer oSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    return (T)oSer.Deserialize(oStrm);
}
```